# A few questions about MySQL transactions

Tags: mysql, transactions

I am new on MySQL and would like to learn more about it. I am reading through myseql doc, which at the moment is difficult to understand.

---

Can you please explain, are these true or false?

**1** - In MySQL there is no way to undo update or delete queries that have already taken place. For example there have been 1900 queries within past 24 hours. None can be undone.

**2** - It is ONLY possible to rollback the current transaction in MySQL.

**3** - Savepoints are destroyed after the transaction is over. In other words it is not possible to create save points for 10 am today.

**4** - Savepoints and rollback are only effective within the current transaction and after the commit has been done they die.

**Question:**

**1** - What is the point of rollback or transaction if it is ONLY possible to rollback the current transaction?

If the transaction is wrong why run it?

---

EDIT:

I created a savepoint like this:

```
start transaction;
savepoint behnam;
commit;
```

Then ran a few update and delete queries. Then tried to rollback to that savepoint:

```
rollback to savepoint behnam
```

and I get:

```
#1305 - SAVEPOINT behnam does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are storing timestamp when the data is inserted then you can fire a query to delete past 24 hours. But you cant undo them.
2. Yes in some cases its possible. kindly refer [rollback and commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)
3. I think savepoints are only deleted when they are overwritten so if u do a transaction with same savepoint as previous one, it will overwrite the last savepoint and so you cant go back
4. Yes all save points are deleted after the current transaction is committed. refer this 
   [savepoints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/savepoint.html)